# DOM TreeWalker to return all text nodes

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to get access to all text nodes within a given element, so that I can isolate words and wrap them in spans.

`TreeWalker` seems to be the API for the job, but I'm finding it to be extremely unintuitive. Neither the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/traversal.html) nor the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) (usually so good at explaining arcane DOM APIs) are self-evident to my eyes.

My first assumption was that all I needed to pass was the right filter as second argument - something like `document.createTreeWalker( element, NodeFilter.TEXT_NODE )`. But this seems to stop as soon as it encounters a non-text node:

```js
wordWrap( document.body )

function wordWrap( element ){
  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker( element, NodeFilter.TEXT_NODE )
  var node
  var text
  var word

  while( node = nodes.nextNode() ){
    text = node.nodeValue.replace( /(^\s+|\s+$)/, '' ).split( /\s+/g )

    while( text.length ){
      word = document.createElement( 'span' )

      word.className = 'word'

      word.innerText = text.shift()

      node.parentNode.insertBefore( word, node )

      if( text.length )
        node.parentNode.insertBefore( document.createTextNode( ' ' ), node )
        }

    node.parentNode.removeChild( node )
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  background: #fee;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
Contact us at <a href="mailto:email@example.com">email@example.com</a> for submissions &#38; other enquiries.
```

So I assume this is an opportunity to use the third filter argument of the `TreeWalker`, as well as the extra properties on `NodeFilter`. If a filter method's valid return values are `FILTER_ACCEPT`, `FILTER_REJECT` & `FILTER_SKIP`, then I reason that by accepting element nodes as well as text nodes in the second argument, I can specify that text nodes should be accepted and the rest skipped. But this seems to give the same results - no text nodes are picked up within or after the anchor:

```js
wordWrap( document.body )

function wordWrap( element ){
  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(
    element,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT | NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    { acceptNode : function( node ){
      if( node.nodeType === node.TEXT_NODE )
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT
      else 
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_SKIP
    } } 
  )
  var node
  var text
  var word

  while( node = nodes.nextNode() ){
    text = node.nodeValue.replace( /(^\s+|\s+$)/, '' ).split( /\s+/g )

    while( text.length ){
      word = document.createElement( 'span' )

      word.className = 'word'

      word.innerText = text.shift()

      node.parentNode.insertBefore( word, node )

      if( text.length )
        node.parentNode.insertBefore( document.createTextNode( ' ' ), node )
        }

    node.parentNode.removeChild( node )
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  background: #fee;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
Contact us at <a href="mailto:email@example.com">email@example.com</a> for submissions &#38; other enquiries.
```

By this point I'm convinced recursively iterating through the tree using DOM1 methods would be easier, like in this snippet:

```js
wordWrap( document.body )

function wordWrap( element ){
  textNodes( element ).forEach( function( node ){
    var text = node.nodeValue.split( /\s+/g )
    var word

    while( text.length ){
      word = document.createElement( 'span' )

      word.className = 'word'

      word.innerText = text.shift()

      node.parentNode.insertBefore( word, node )

      if( text.length )
        node.parentNode.insertBefore( document.createTextNode( ' ' ), node )
        }

    node.parentNode.removeChild( node )
  } )
}

function textNodes( element ){
  var nodes = []

  Array.prototype.forEach.call( element.childNodes, function( child ){
    if( child.nodeType === child.TEXT_NODE )
      nodes = nodes.concat( child )
      else if( child.nodeType === child.ELEMENT_NODE )
        nodes = nodes.concat( textNodes( child ) )
        } )

  return nodes
}
```

```css
.word {
  background: #fee;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
Contact us at <a href="mailto:email@example.com">email@example.com</a> for submissions &#38; other enquiries.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I guess `node.parentNode.removeChild( node )` is the problem - you're removing the current node from the DOM, so the walker will find no `.nextNode()` from the detached state.

Comment: @Bergi that sounds like the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I missing?

`node.parentNode.removeChild(node)` is the problem - you're removing the current node from the DOM, so the walker will find no `.nextNode()` from the there.

You should either advance the walker before removing the node, or just not remove it and instead shrink its content (to what is left over when you've moved out all words).

```js
wordWrap(document.body);

function wordWrap( element ){
  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, null);
  var node;
  while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
    var p = node.parentNode;
    var text = node.nodeValue;
    var m;
    while(m = text.match(/^(\s*)(\S+)/)) {
      text = text.slice(m[0].length);
      p.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(m[1]), node);
      var word = p.insertBefore(document.createElement('span'), node);
      word.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m[2]));
      word.className = 'word';
    }
    node.nodeValue = text;
  }
}
```

```css
.word {
  background: #faa;
  padding: 0 .5em 0 0;
}
```

```html
Contact us at <a href="mailto:email@example.com">email @ example.com</a> for submissions &#38; other enquiries.
```

<sub>Notice that the correct filter is `NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT`, not `.TEXT_NODE`, and that in older browser the four arguments are not optional.</sub>

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - using the iterative nature of match is a very nice touch.

Comment: @Barney: In this case, I've actually used `text = text.slice(…)` for the iteration. You could however have done `var re = /^(\s*)(\S+)/g; while (m = text.match(re)) …` with the global flag set

Comment: ah, I see. The tricksiness of low-level JS API side-effects always befuddles me. Prefer the match side-effect in theory because iteration mechanism is in the loop condition, but the match behaviour is arguably more obscure.