# Find and Replace only Whole word in HTML using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all the occurrences of a particular word in the web page using javascript.

Sample Sentence = `"Hi Guys, I have a lot of things. The things are good. They are beautiful-things. Look at /home/things.html"`

I am using

```
document.body.innerHTML = 
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\bthings\b/g, function (x) {
return 'OBJECTS';
});
```

But this replaced like this

```
Hi Guys, I have a lot of OBJECTS. The OBJECTS are good. They are beautiful-OBJECTS. Look at /home/OBJECTS.html
```

I want to replace only whole words. Not (beautiful-things), (/home/things.html) should not be replaced. I want to replace only (things).

Comment: You better hope `things` doesn't appear in the HTML parts (eg. class names)...

Comment: You can use a [Treewalker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31956960/104380) to traverse all textNodes and find the text to change, depending if your target node has children or not. if not, you can simply use `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ritesh answer will work fine most of the time, but it won't when the word you want to replace is the first one in the text (unless you put an extra white space before it, which you probably don't want to).

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/(^|\s)things\b/gi, m => m.replace(/things/i, 'OBJECTS'));
```

```html
Things. Hi Guys, I have a lot of things. The things are good. They are beautiful-things. Look at /home/things.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 
document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\sthings\b/g,' OBJECTS');
```

```html
Hi Guys, I have a lot of things. The things are good. They are beautiful-things. Look at /home/things.html
```